# Выборка из базы, по ограниченной дистанции

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Имеется база, в которой содержатся объекты с колонками id, latitude, longitude. Так же знаем координаты пользователя. Есть ли возможность средствсами `sqlite` сделать выборку из базы таким образом, чтобы доставались только те объекты, дистанция до которых не будет привышать к примеру 400 метров, то есть `WHERE distance<400` ?

Comment: Для начала вам потребуется пересчитать координаты на метры. Гугл говорит, что это не самая простая задача. Либо использовать формулу с кучей синусов и косинусов, либо использовать морские мили, позже конвертируя в метры. Хотя все зависит от того, насколько точно вам надо вычислять значение.

Comment: Научите конвертировать в метры. Мне очень надо. Хочу нобелевку получить.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Places WHERE acos(sin(1.3963) * sin(Lat) + cos(1.3963) * cos(Lat) * cos(Lon - (-0.6981))) * 6371 <= 1000;` - Есть такой метод, где 1000, это дистанция, правда, надо будет создать свои функции в sqlite

Comment: @bukkojot огорчу, гугл уже знает  1 морская миля = 1852 метров

Comment: @Виктор, мне не мили, мне все координаты на земле сконвертить надо. Я тут как раз делаю свой гугломапс и мне надоело все эти градусы использовать.

Comment: Всем спасибо за подсказки, завтра буду пробовать)